# Order of removing object from two collections affects memory management?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management, collections

My algorithm is pretty simple. Add an item to a cache. The item is stored in both an `NSMutableArray` and an `NSMutableDictionary`. The array serves as a FIFO queue, where if I pass a specified maximum size, I delete the oldest items until the size is lower than the allowed maximum.

When I remove an item, I first remove if from the array, and then from the dictionary. Then I have problems because the item seems to be over-released (so says the debugger, i.e. "does not appear to point to a valid object").

```
- (void) addItem:(NSData *)value forKey:(NSString *)key {
    ApiResponseCacheItem *item = [[ApiResponseCacheItem alloc] init];
    item.cacheKey = key;
    item.cacheValue = value;

    [queue addObject:item];
    [item release];
    [dictionary setObject:item forKey:key];

    size += [value length];

    while (size > kMaxCacheSize && [queue count] > 0) {
        ApiResponseCacheItem *oldestItem = [queue objectAtIndex:0];
        size -= [oldestItem.cacheValue length];
        // remove oldest item
        [queue removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        [dictionary removeObjectForKey:oldestItem.cacheKey];
    }
}
```

Now, I change the order: first I remove the object from the dictionary, and then from the array, leaving everything else exactly the same. Now all is fine.

```
while (size > kMaxCacheSize && [queue count] > 0) {
    ApiResponseCacheItem *oldestItem = [queue objectAtIndex:0];
    size -= [oldestItem.cacheValue length];
    [dictionary removeObjectForKey:oldestItem.cacheKey];
    // remove oldest item
    [queue removeObjectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Please explain.

Comment: Does `-[ApiResponseCacheItem init]` return an autoreleased object? By convention it should **not** but maybe it's poorly written.

Comment: "Please do not comment on anything except my question." - please do not instruct volunteers on how to respond.

Comment: @WTP, no it doesn't. In fact, I did not override init for that class.

Comment: Thank you for your useless, snarky sarcasm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, first of all @WTP is absolutely right, and you should accept his answer. +1 to him.

The right thing to do is not touch 'item' after you have released it. And certainly don't pass it around to other unsuspecting methods after you have already released it.

But, having said that, if you want to understand why the order made a difference as to whether you survived the bug or not, the key is to remember that NSDictionary doesn't retain its keys, it **copies them**.

So the crashing sequence was like this:

1. You alloc/init item - Retain count +1
2. You add it to the array - Retain count +2
3. You release it prematurely - Retain count +1
4. You use it as a key in the dictionary - Retain count of your object
   still +1 (the dictionary made a copy of the object for its own use)
5. You remove it from the array - Retain count 0 - object is gone
6. You hand a dangling pointer off to -[NSMutableDictionary
   removeObjectForKey:] and down you go.

The lucky sequence where the bug didn't surface:

1. You alloc/init -> +1
2. You add it to the array -> +2
3. You release it -> +1
4. You use it as a key -> +1
5. You hand it off to removeObjectForKey: -> Still +1 and you avoided
   the crash
6. You remove it from the array -> Retain count goes to 0

Again, you should do what @WTP advised. This is just background info if you're curious. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

This code:

```
[queue addObject:item];
[item release];
[dictionary setObject:item forKey:key];
```

You are using `item` after you have released it. You should never do this. Move `[item release];` after `[dictionary setObject:item forKey:key];`:

```
[queue addObject:item];
[dictionary setObject:item forKey:key];
[item release];
```

Comment: But, doesn't adding it to the queue increase the retain count by 1?

Comment: I think however the code will run fine, since item will never get released (it is being retained by the array) but I think the order of operations is confusing the analyser.

Comment: @Ovesh You (should pretend you) don't know what it does with it. `queue` may copy it, it may do its own kind of memory management, whatever. Once you release an object, never use the variable that points to it (`item` in this case) again, unless you assign it again to something else.

Comment: OK, then. First of all, what is the correct idiom for adding an object to an array, assuming I'm going to access it later? Just release it after adding it?
Secondly, it doesn't answer the question that I asked. Technically, this shouldn't be happening. Because we know NSArray retains its objects.

Comment: @Ovesh `NSArray` retains the object, yes, according to the docs. If you want to add an object to an array, use `-[NSArray addObject:]`. If you want to use the *variable* (`item` in this case) again, don't release it. Release it when you are done with it.

Comment: Sorry, really sorry. But I just don't understand the difference between object and variable in this discussion. Why should it matter? And why does it matter when an object is removed (later on in the code) from the array?
Are you saying that NSArray may be monitoring the retain count of an object I added to it?